# How to form static data with the structure like array of objects in swift 4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray

Currently, I'm building an app using the Swift platform. I need to show static data like an array of objects structure because I need to load data on UITableView section and rows. Below is the example array of objects structure in objective C. I need to replicate the same thing in Swift.

```
NSArray *dummyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"India",@"team",@"280",@"score",@"5",@"wickets", nil],
                       [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SouthAfrica",@"team",@"279",@"score",@"9",@"wickets", nil],
                       nil];

NSMutableArray *demoArrayOfObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                      [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"17-03-2018",@"date",@"Ind win by 5 wickets",@"result",@"SouthAfrica",@"Place",dummyArray,@"data", nil], nil];

NSLog(@"demoArrayOfObjects = %@",demoArrayOfObjects);
```

Output:

```
demoArrayOfObjects = (
    {
    Place = SouthAfrica;
    data =         (
                    {
            score = 280;
            team = India;
            wickets = 5;
        },
                    {
            score = 279;
            team = SouthAfrica;
            wickets = 9;
        }
    );
    date = "17-03-2018";
    result = "Ind win by 5 wickets";
    }
)
```

Comment: as i understand you need this statuc structure written in swift?

Comment: @JabaOdishelashvili yes I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pseudo code might help you implement datasource in swift.

func prepareMatchInfo () -> Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>{

```
    var arrayOfMatches : Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>();
    
    var arrayOfScores : Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>();
    arrayOfScores.append(getTeamScore(teamName: "India", score: "280", wickets: "5"));
    arrayOfScores.append(getTeamScore(teamName: "South Africa", score: "279", wickets: "6"));

    arrayOfMatches.append(getMatchInfo(place: "South Africa", data: arrayOfScores, date: Date(), result: "India Won by 5 Wickets"));
    
    return arrayOfMatches;
}

func getMatchInfo (place:String, data:Array<Dictionary<String,String>>, date:Date, result:String) -> Dictionary<String, Any>{
    var dict : Dictionary<String, Any> = Dictionary();
    dict["Place"] = place;
    dict["Data"] = data;
    dict["Date"] = date;
    dict["Result"] = result;
    return dict;
}

func getTeamScore (teamName:String, score:String, wickets:String) -> Dictionary<String, String>{
    var dict : Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary();
    dict["TeamName"] = teamName;
    dict["Score"] = score;
    dict["Wickets"] = wickets;
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: why swift doesn't return the `array of objects should be JSON structure` ?

Comment: Could you tell me how to get all `data` counts from `arrayOfMatches` to set `UITbleViewDataSource` `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it, written in swift 4

```
let dataDictionary1 = ["team": "India", "score": "280", "wickets": "5"]
let dataDictionary2 = ["team": "SouthAfrica", "score": "279", "wickets": "9"]
let dummyArray = [dataDictionary1, dataDictionary2]

let fullDictionary = ["date": "17-03-2018", "result": "Ind win by 5 wickets", "Place": "SouthAfrica", "data": dummyArray] as [String : Any]
let demoArrayOfObjects = [fullDictionary]

print(demoArrayOfObjects)
```

to convert json:

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: demoArrayOfObjects, options: []) {
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("json - \(jsonString)")
    }
}
```

Comment: @ JabaOdishelashvili when I change like  `as [String : AnyObject]`  instead of `as [String : Any]` on 5th line from your answer.  Then the output is like below,
`[["Place": SouthAfrica, "date": 17-03-2018, "data": <Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x600000238620>(
{
    score = 280;
    team = India;
    wickets = 5;
},
{
    score = 279;
    team = SouthAfrica;
    wickets = 9;
}
)
, "result": Ind win by 5 wickets]]` is it normal ? I mean JSON structure.

Comment: No you should serialize it to json.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array of structs that conform to the Encodable protocol, instead of using dictionaries:

**Note: Swift 4 only**

More info at Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

```
struct CricketData : Encodable {
   let country: String
   let score: Int
   let wickets: Int
}

struct Tournament : Encodable {
   let data: [CricketData]
   let hostCountry: String
   let result: String
   let date: Date
}

let array = [Tournament] // here you should create your data array with all the info about the games
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(array)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check it and I will update to you.